# MSTest.exe not able to load ADO.NET Data providers?

Tags: unit-testing, ado.net, mstest

I'm having a really strange issue with MSTest.  I have a test that is more of an integration test, and needs to connect to the database. It does this by getting the ADO.NET data provider factory through a call to:

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
```

In my app.config file, I have:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Oracle Data Provider" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess" />
```

This *works perfectly fine* and the test passes if I run it in Visual Studio. However, if I open a command prompt, and run it using `MSTest.exe /testcontainer:...` Then my test fails, with the exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message:  Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
```

The odd thing is that if I query the DBProviderFacotry classes, I do see my "Oracle.DataAccess.Client" provider, but trying to actually get an instance of it throws an exception:

```
var name = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses().Rows[1]["InvariantName"]; // returns "Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
var fact = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client"); // throws exception
```

Again, this *only* fails when run from the MSTest.exe command line, and works fine in VisualStudio 2008. Anyone have any ideas?

---

**Update:**

I found out another interesting detail... In my app.config, I actually do a clear of the provider collection before adding my oracle entry, because if it already existed in machine.config, it would cause errors:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <clear />
    <add name="Oracle Data Provider" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess" />
```

Now, what I just found is that if I completely remove this from the app.config, and don't specify the DbProviderFactories at all, then it works fine!

Strange...

---

**Update 2**

OK, I guess I sort of figured this out.  In my app.config, if I specify the full/strong name for the assembly, then it works, in both VisualStudio, and from the command line:

```
<add name="Oracle Data Provider"
  invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
  description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" 
  type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

But the short name only works in VisualStudio, not on the command line:

```
<add name="Oracle Data Provider"
  invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
  description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle"
  type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess" />
```

Now I just wish I understood why... :)

Comment: I encountered very similar problems with SQLite during MSTest unit tests. I didn't have an app.config, so what I wound up doing was adding [DeploymentItem] attributes to the affected tests to ensure that the DLLs got deployed, and that seems to have solved my issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but I finally figured this out:

My Oracle.DataAccess.dll does end up in my \bin\Debug folder when VisualStudio builds it. However, when MSTest.exe runs, it does not copy that .dll to the new folder where the test is actually run. For some reason it copies the other 30-some files, but not that one?

Anyway, thats why adding the full assembly name worked; because then it could load it from the GAC instead of the local folder.

Comment: <HEADSLAP> - Thanks for responding with this information. I totally forgot to include the Oracle DLL's I needed in the bin and this was the "you dummy" reminder I needed. I think I only lost about 3 hours chasing this one! LOL

Comment: We had a similar issue except our issue was we had 2 versions in the gac and we wanted the older version. it kept loading the newest version. we had to add system.data element to the config file of our NUnit test assembly (and for good measure the web.config) .

Comment: I was hitting this issue also but it was only effecting me on our build server.  Compiler optimizations were to thank.  mstest reflects the test assembly to determine what assemblies to "deploy".

If you want a specific version to deploy with your test, you can add a method and decorate with [AssemblyInitialize].  in there put a couple dummy references to the types you need... ie.

var _ = typeof(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine)
_.GetMethods();   // this is required to keep release optimizations from compiling it out.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue using the following code:

```
[ClassInitialize]
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void InitTestSuite(TestContext testContext)
{
    // You use the capability for configuring the behavior of the EF-provider:
    var instanceSql = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    var instanceOracle = Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.Instance;
}
```